# Using a variable in select

Tags: mysql, subquery, case

I have a query like this

```
SELECT ID, ... , 
       (SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM Projects) As NewestDate,
       (CASE
           WHEN (NewestDate > NOW()) THEN 'More Work is coming'  
           ELSE 'Send Vendors to work' 
       END) Message
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

i.e. I am trying to use the value of NewestDate inside a CASE. Is this possible? or is something like this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly No. You could use the same statement twice though:

```
SELECT ID, ... , 
       (SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM Projects) As NewestDate,
       (CASE
           WHEN ((SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM Projects) > NOW()) 
           THEN 'More Work is coming'  
           ELSE 'Send Vendors to work' 
       END) Message
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

If you want to use the already calculated one, use subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (
        case 
            when (NewestDate > NOW())
                then 'More Work is coming'
            else 'Send Vendors to work'
            end
        ) Message
from (
    select ID,
        ...,
        (
            select MAX(EndDate)
            from Projects
            ) as NewestDate
    from SOME_TABLE
    ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join against the newest date.  This would be quicker than a subquery every row.

```
SELECT ID, ... , 
       nd.NewestDate,
       (CASE
           WHEN (nd.NewestDate > NOW()) THEN 'More Work is coming'  
           ELSE 'Send Vendors to work' 
       END) Message
FROM SOME_TABLE
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(EndDate) AS NewestDate FROM Projects
) nd
```